# CakePHP BinaryTree using Tree behavior

Tags: cakephp

Is it possible to create a **binary tree** using `TreeBehavior`? I just tried it but the `lft` and `rght` values doesn't seem to point to the child nodes ID (in this case, row ID).

Comment: `lft` and `rght` are not ids, they are the order in the tree (and have nothing to do with the primary key or the parent id) - see [cakephp-and-tree-structures](http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/02/17/cakephp-and-tree-structures/). You should not touch them as the behavior handles them internally.

Comment: I understand. I believe that I'm better off handling the binary tree myself, I don't think the `TreeBehavior` would help me at all. Thanks anyway.